# Hide/Show Fields to user based on a group permission in sharepoint 2010.?

Tags: drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement to show a drop down list to a particular group member and hide the same dropdownlist if another group member is logged in.Is there any way to do this with Sharepoint Out-of-box Feature ?

- This Drop down list is in Default Edit Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can try this

```
 SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mossportal/"); 

 SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

 SPList myList = web.Lists["My List"];

 SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;

  bool bPermission =   myList.Permissions.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPRights.AddListItems); 



System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox fldAdminComment =   (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)this.FindControl("ctl00$m $g_80f418ab_bb35_4ece_9238_a13ec0c06fd8$ctl00$ctl04$ctl02$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField"); 

System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox fldStatus = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)this.FindControl("ctl00$m $g_80f418ab_bb35_4ece_9238_a13ec0c06fd8$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField"); 

if (bPermission)

 { 

fldAdminComment.Enabled = true;

fldStatus.Enabled = true;

 } 

else

 {

fldAdminComment.Enabled = false;

 fldStatus.Enabled = false;

 }

  web.Dispose();
```

please  change your field textbox id.

Answer (score 0):

you can check by below condition

```
 bool check = SPlist.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser,SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems);
```

Hops its helps.